# Using database output in HTML Select Tag with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the following working perfectly on a wordpress site.

```
<?php 

global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'show' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_title ASC" );
$options = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
$options[$result->post_title] =  $result->post_title;
}

echo '<select class="field" name="djshow">';
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
echo "<option value='$key'" . ( $_GET['show'] == $value ? " selected='selected'" : "" ) . ">$value</option>";
}
'</select>';

?>
```

It searches the database for every instance of *post_title* from *wp_posts* where the *post_type* is **show** and the *post_status* is **public**. It then sorts it and outputs it to the array before populating a Select tag with a list of every *post_title* that matches.

At the moment it outputs the *post_title* to both the option value and name fields....

What I would like to do is select another field *ID* in the original query to populate the option value while the *post_title* populates the name.

So the select would read something like this when rendered in html :

```
<option value="15">Post Title 1</option>
<option value="18">Post Title 2</option>
<option value="23">Post Title 3</option>
etc...
```

I think the correct query I need to use is this (but correct me if i'm wrong)

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_title,ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'show' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_title ASC" );
```

But that's where my limited knowledge let's me down...

How would I assign the output of *ID* to the option value and *post_title* to the name of the select tag?

Comment: "SELECT post_title,ID FROM wp_posts..."  You don't use "and" in the field list for the select, just in the where clause.  Here you use comma.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that out WJK. Will edit now to show the fix. How would I formulate the rest of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query for several values you can use a comma to separate them.
In your code

```
post_title AND ID
```

should be

```
post_title, ID
```

Your return value are in $results, your foreach could be

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
echo "<option value='$result->ID'" . ( $_GET['show'] == $result->ID ? " selected='selected'" : "" ) . ">$result->post_title</option>";
}
```

not sure if your $_GET holds the post_title or the ID

Comment: Yep that is perfect. Thanks so much. I just didn't understand the logic of how to separate the values but as well as making it work you've taught me something new ;)

Answer (score 0):

After changing the SQL to include both `post_title` and `ID` you really only need to fix this part:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $options[$result->post_title] =  $result->post_title;
}
```

Which should now be:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $options[$result->ID] =  $result->post_title;
}
```

Because in the next `foreach` what you have in `$key` is coming from what you put in the brackets there, and `$value` from the right side of the assignment.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. You explained that very clearly, many thanks!